# Convert Directive1[Option[String]] to String scala

Tags: scala, akka

I am new to scala. I have written some lines of code which give me cookie. Something like this:

```
var dataCookie = optionalCookie("user_session").map(_.map(_.value));
```

`dataCookie` is an `Directive1[Option[String]]`. I want it to be `String`. How to get `String` from it?

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome to SO!

So, let's consider result type by details `Directive1[Option[String]]`:

- `Directive1` - akka-http class responsible for incoming request transformation or parsing incoming request. Please, see for more details: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/index.html#directives
- `Option` - Scala standard library monad describes possible absent value.

Hence, you can not just retrieve the cookies as a string you need handle absent cookie value and inbuilt directive into another routes.
Please, see next code snippet for example:

```
higherRoute ~> optionalCookie("user_session") {
    case Some(session) => 
       println(s"User session: $session") // handle present session cookie value 
    case None => //handle absent session cookie value 
}
```

where `higherRoute` is just an example of `Route` where you need attach given piece of logic.

See for more details official documentation:

- https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/cookie-directives/cookie.html#cookie
- https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/cookie-directives/optionalCookie.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: So can i set any variable inside Some(). Because i tried doing that it is not setting

Comment: No you can't - `session` is let's say val. If you wan't some how modify it, you need to declare new local variable, something like `val updatedSession = session + "update"`

Comment: So I cannot use var and then use that variable outside of Some()

Comment: Not really: You can use `session` inside `Some(session) => ` you just can not re-assign it is value to another. If you don't need to do it use it as is,  in other case create new `var` or `val` if need change original `session`  value

Comment: @dharmeshsingh I've updated code example for more details.

Comment: I tried following but getting empty value in sesionData:
var sesionData = "";
   val route = optionalCookie("user_session") {
       case Some(nameCookie) => 
         sessionData = nameCookie.content
         complete(s"The logged in user is '${nameCookie}'")
       case None             => complete("No user logged in")
   }

Comment: 1) That's a very bad idea to update external `var` as you described, because of lot of reasons out of scope for this question. 2) Check `user_session` cookie value you sent if it is empty

Comment: Not it not. Because I have tried it by writing this entire optionalCookie in api just for check. it is giving proper response. Only thing now is i don't want to use it as api I want to use optionalCookie inside some method and use it

Comment: you will find one parent question around it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60381041/how-to-use-some-and-none-case-with-in-method-scala

Comment: @dharmeshsingh Excuse me, please, but further discussion is out of scope of this question. Your initial question was just about optional cookie retrial. If you face other issues - please, create another question.